# Como usar a função calc() com o js?

Tags: javascript

Preciso diminuir `20px` de 100% com o *javascript .style*

Tentativas:

```
circulo[0].style.left = "calc(100%" + "-90px)";

circulo[0].style.left = "calc(" + 100 +"%" + "-20px)";
```

Comment: Esse `calc` é *CSS*,Veja a [documentação - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), também tem um [tutorial no site do Maujor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/css3-funcao-css-calc.php)

Comment: to tentando fazer um range com dois botoes para pesquisar por idade.
nada de uijquery procurei na net mas nao achei nada que funcionasse no meu site

Comment: Por que está concatenando? Já tentou `"calc(100% - 20px)"`?

Comment: Eu ia dizer o mesmo que o @sam disse, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/0ek397qd/6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `calc()` deve ter um espaço antes e após o operador:

```
calc(valor1 - valor2)
           ↑ ↑
```

No seu caso, essas concatenações são desnecessárias. Deve usar concatenação quando o valor usado for dinâmico representado por alguma variável, não valores fixos. E mesmo assim, a sua concatenação resultaria num valor inválido da propriedade:

`"calc(" + 100 +"%" + "-20px)";` seria `"calc(100%-20px)";`

Veja que faltam os espaços antes e depois do operador `-`.

O correto seria:

```
circulo[0].style.left = "calc(100% - 20px)";
```

> Lembrando que para mover o elemento com a propriedade `left`, o
>   elemento deve possuir um `position` diferente de `static` (padrão):

```
position: relative ou fixed ou absolute;
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
var circulo = document.getElementsByClassName("circulo");
circulo[0].style.left = "calc(100% - 50px)";
```

```css
.circulo{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="circulo"></div>
```

Veja que no exemplo acima, a `div` de `100px` está com `left` de `100%` (o que faria ela ficar fora da tela) mas possui um recuo de `50px` (metade), ficando visível a metade de `50px`.